# redirect_to Post method ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, methods, response.redirect

I have the following

games_controller

```
def sheet
  @game=params[:id]
  @champ=params[:ch]
  @w_team=params[:wt]
  @b_team=params[:bt]
  @champ_id=params[:chi]
  @w_team_id=params[:wti]
  @b_team_id=params[:bti]
  render template: "games/sheet.html.erb"
```

end

scripts.js

```
function to_sheet(id){
   tokentag = $('#tokentag').val();

   var champ = $("#champ option:selected").text();
   var w_team = $("#team_W option:selected").text();
   var b_team = $("#team_B option:selected").text();
   var champ_id = $("#champ option:selected").val();
   var w_team_id = $("#team_W option:selected").val();
   var b_team_id = $("#team_B option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
     url:    "/games/sheet",
     type:   "POST",
     data:   {"authenticity_token": tokentag,game_id:id, w_team:w_team, w_team_id:w_team_id, b_team:b_team, b_team_id:b_team_id, champ:champ, champ_id:champ_id},
     success: function(response){
        alert('hola');
     }
   });
 }
```

routes.rb

```
resources :games
  post 'games/sheet' => 'games#sheet'
```

My problem is that games/sheet.html.erb in not display in the web page (is not redirected to it)... it renders only in the "preview" of the debuging part. Do you understand?

I tried with redirect redirect_to :controller=>'games',:action=>'sheet' but it didnt work

Thanks!

Comment: paste logs too... check your `rails s` console

Comment: If you want the response to be inserted somewhere on the page you'll have to write some javascript to do that

Comment: Rails s console doesn't throw error.

Comment: What i want is a redirect, not to receive it in the js

Comment: Change your javascript to redirect on success. So instead of `alert('hola')` you would do: `window.location.assign("/games/whateverActionIwantToRedirectTo");`

Comment: I don't know why if i do that is redirected to the landing page :/